# Route only specific IP series traffic from eth0 and rest all to wlan0

Tags: linux, networking, routing

I am no good at networks so this might be naive question.

I am using Ubuntu, and connected on LAN as well as WiFi. LAN is my internal network that isn't accessible from outside. I need WiFi for accessing the internet.

I think it should be pretty straightforward to route all traffic towards `10.*.*.*` to `eth0` and everything else to `wlan0` something like that.

Can someone suggest command for this?

**Update:**

```
ip route list

default via 10.2.133.254 dev eth0  proto static 
10.0.0.0/8 dev eth0  scope link 
10.2.133.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.2.133.104  metric 1 
172.16.32.0/21 dev wlan0  proto kernel  scope link  src 172.16.39.177  metric 9
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a privelaged user (root or sudo) running the following should suffice:

```
# ip route add 10.0.0.0/8 dev eth0
# ip route add default via x.x.x.x
```

where the last x.x.x.x is the ip number of your default gateway for your wifi.

The default route might already be in place so you perhaps don't have to issue that one, check with 'ip route list'

Comment: Please check updated question, I ran the first command you suggested

Comment: The default route now is to the 10 network, that is not what you want. I think it is best for you to delete the whole route and just issue those two commands in my answer after that. Note though that by using the ip route command these routes will not be permanent, they will change upon reboot. To make them permanent you have to edit some files which depend on what linux you are running. This also means that if you make some mistakes with route now you can reboot and start afresh.

Comment: Great! Thanks. I'll give it a try. How do I delete them though?